Proof that there exists a bijection between X and $X\cup A$
So we have that $X$ is a uncountable set and $A$ is a countable set.
We want to prove that there exists a bijection between $X$ and $X\cup A$.
Proof:
Consider the countable subset $B$ of $X$. We define $A_0:=A-X$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are countable we know that there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow {A_0\cup B}$. We have that there exists a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$. Because $g$ is bijection  we know that there exists $g^{-1}$. We will now construct a bijection $h:X\rightarrow X\cup A$.
$h(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x\in X-B \\f \circ g^{-1}(x)  & \text{if } x\in B \end{cases}$
I'm not sure if this bijection really works. So my question is if this bijection works.
I think this isn't injective in general and therefore doesn't work.

Well, currently this gives you a bite lion between $X$ and $(X \setminus B) \cup A$ as long as $A \cap X = \emptyset$, because you haven't found a replacement for the elements of $B$.

How could I fix this? I started with the approach above but recognised how bad this works out.

Hint: instead of just $A$, consider $A \cup B$.

But isn't the approach completely wrong because we don't know if $A\cap X=\emptyset$

Then you can fix this by considering $A_0 = A \setminus X$, so either way you're fine, it just means you have slightly more to write about.

@BrunoB Thank your for your help. I have edited my question. Is my new attempt right? Maybe I have misunderstood your hint.

Things seem to have gotten out of sequence. For example, you use the symbol $B$ before you say what it is. I think if you present things in a logical sequence it will work.

There is a theorem which says that if $A$ is dominated by $B$ then $A \cup B$ is equinumerous with $B$. The proof is not that trivial. This theorem can be used to solve this problem. Is the full theorem required?

As said in the comments above, you should go about things in the proper order. But you have at least worked through the gist of it, so I'll allow myself to answer.
Define $A_0 := A \setminus (X \cap A)$, which is at most countable since $A$ is countable.
If $A_0$ were empty, then there was nothing to do since the identity $X \to X$ is already a bijection, thus we can assume that $A_0 \neq \emptyset$. There are now two cases which work exactly the same.
Whether $A_0$ is finite of cardinality $n \geq 1$ or $A_0$ is infinite countable, consider any infinite countable set $B \subset X$. Such a set exists, otherwise $X$ would be countable.
Choose any two bijections $f : B \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g : A_0 \cup B \to \mathbb{N}$, then define $h := g^{-1} \circ f : B \to A_0 \cup B$, which is a bijection as composition of bijections.
Then we can construct the following map:
$$j : x \in X \,\,\longmapsto\,\, \begin{cases} x \text{ if } x \in X \setminus B\\ h(x) \text{ if } x \in B\end{cases} \in X \cup A$$
$j$ is surjective because the range of $h$ is $B \cup A_0$, so that the range of $j$ is $X \cup A_0 = X \cup A$, and $j$ is well-defined and injective because the domains and ranges of the injective functions that are the identity $X \setminus B \to X \setminus B$ and $h : B \to B \cup A_0$ respectively have empty intersection.
Therefore $j$ is bijective, and we are done.

Thank you very much!  Sorry that the logical order was reversed. I was in a hurry when I wrote that

Let $X$ and $A$ be two subsets, where X is infinite. Suppose there exists an injection $j:A\longrightarrow X$. Then the function $X\cup A\longrightarrow X$ defined by
\begin{equation}\tag*{}
x\longmapsto \begin{cases}x\quad&\text{if}\;x\in X\\ j(x)\quad&\text{if}\;x\in A\setminus X\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is an injection, plus we can easily find an injection $X\longrightarrow X\cup A$. We conclude by the Schröder-Bernstein theorem that there exists a bijection $X\cup A\longrightarrow X$.
In your problem, since $A$ is countable and $X$ is uncountable, there must be an injection $A\longrightarrow X$, hence a bijection $X\cup A\longrightarrow X$ as said before.

If $x_1 \in X, x_2 \in A\setminus X$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, where $f$ is your function, we should get a contradiction.
